# Shutting down a laptop with the power button

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, hibernate, overheating

I've always had the power button on my HP ProBook 4540s set to hibernate the machine and it's always worked fine until now.

Recently I experienced what I'm sure was an overheating issue: after using the machine on a pretty thick table cloth for an entire day, I started getting blue screens intermittently, and on rebooting was met with `PXE-E61 Media test failure, check cable` for half a second, followed by `BootDevice Not Found`. I followed typical procedure - reseated drive, reset BIOS, ran HP's memory/HDD diagnostic tools (no errors were found). It didn't work at first, but luckily and randomly I was able to boot back into Windows much later. I also ran a `chkdsk` and no errors were found.

Now, the machine seems to be stable again after not using the table cloth surface, but when I hibernate the machine, powering it back on gives the boot error. Shutting down is fine.

1. What could I have damaged that's making the hibernate function do this? Can I expect any future issues?
2. If I set the power button to shut down, is it safe to use it when lots of programs are open? (besides obviously losing any unsaved work)

Answer (score 0):

when booting your HDD has failed, then the following BIOS option was booting from the NET (PXE) and also failed ("PXE-E61 Media test failure" means you have not connection at your Ethernet port) and not having any other boot option available your BIOS said "BootDevice Not Found".

If the test was performed when the PC internally recovered normal temperature that tells you you have/had a problem with your disk, probably caused by the repeated blue-screens and the overall overheat.
I do not think the hardware was permanently affected and I think the software has recovered from HDD errors; I'd say that you will not have more problems if the disk was properly self-recovered.

Comment: You're probably right.. (Thanks for taking the time to reply)